# How many possible set of lines can be perpendicular to a certain lines in 3D ? How does perpendicularity between lines work in 3D?

Tags: geometry, vectors, 3d

Take for example a diagonal line $L$ that lies in $y=0$ (in a cube, with equation $x = t$, $z = -x = -t, y = 0$), that line is perpendicular to line $x = t, z = x = t,y = 0$, and then surprisingsly also perpendicular with space diagonal line with equation $x = t , y = t, z = t$ (surprising if you didn't use vector and use cosine rule instead), and it's also perpendicular to the normal line of $y = 0$ (that is the line $y = t, x = 0, z = 0 $).

My Question :

1) Just how many possible sets of lines are perpendicular to $L$ ? does those set of lines as segment form some kind of circle around that particular line ?

2)What rotation doesn't change the perpendicularity of two lines ?

Comment: Two lines both perpendicular to the same line $L$ at the same point $O$ define a plane perpendicular to $L$: all the lines in that plane passing through $O$ are perpendicular to $L$. The proof is easy.

Comment: Are the only possible set of those perpendicular lines against $L$ can only form exactly 1 planes with $L$ as its normal ?

Comment: Yes: all lines perpendicular to $L$ at point $P$ lie on that plane, and all the lines in that plane passing through $P$ are perpendicular to $L$.

Answer (score 0):

Two lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are perpendicular iff:

- they intersect
- the dot product of their direction vectors is $0$

The set of lines that are perpendicular to a given line form a series of planes, whose normals are parallel to the given line.

Comment: But the space diagonal line that im talking about aren't the normal line of the $y = 0$ which is one of the plane that given line lies on

Comment: And i already know about dot product, im asking about how rotation in 3D can affect perpendicularity of 2 lines, see my edit

Comment: If you recheck your work, some of your lines are not perpendicular with each other, as you claim.

Comment: Im only talking about those three lines being perpendicular to only $L$ not being perpendicular to each other